# Building tree structure in a database-how to fill in the tree one child node at a time?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, tree

I'm building a tree in a MySQL database using an adjacency list so each row has a node_id and a parent_id.

The tree will be filled with data over time and I need to fill it in a certain way:

- Each node has a max of three child nodes
- Fill in each node in the current level one child at a time horizontally
- After all nodes in the current level have one child, return to the beginning of the current level and fill in child node 2 for each node, then repeat with the last child
- After the last node in the current level has three children, start filling in the next level in the same way

So basically I just need help with the algorithm that will determine the parent_id of the node I am inserting. I'd rather not have to traverse the tree with every insert as it will get quite large, but that's fine if it's the only way. I'm building the logic in PHP but pseudocode is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Look into MPTT/nested set tree representations. In a properly nested set it's trivial to figure out the "width" of any particular branch.

Comment: Nah, I'd like to do it in MySQL with relational logic, thanks though